# Chamar div quando for link específico

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo com conteúdo dinâmico em PHP. Tenho uma div que quero que seja mostrada sempre que o link do site for /quem-somos.

Como fazer isso em PHP?

Comment: Algo como `if ($url == '/quem-somos') { show_div(); }`. Para mais detalhes, adicione o código relevante na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar **[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)** para verificar se a URL termina com a string `/quem-somos` ou `/quem-somos/`:

```
<?php
$url_atual = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]; // URL da página atual
$match = preg_match('\/quem-somos[\/]?$/', $url_atual, $matches); // verifica a string na URL
if($matches){ // se casou, carrega a div
?>
<div></div>
<?php
} // fecha o if
?>
```

**[Teste a regex no RegExr](https://regexr.com/3qsc4)**

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi e só você utilizar o modo GET.

```
$url=$_GET['mostrar'];
if($url="quem-somos"){
   echo "<div id='IDdaDiv'> </div>";   
}
```

Assim se a url for site.com/index.php?mostrar=quem-somos
ele vai mostrar a div caso n n vai.
você pode usar URL amigavel para n mostrar o "index.php?mostrar=" e sim so "site.com/quem-somos"